# How can I implement a NodeJS component according to Onion/Clean Architecture principles?

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, components, clean-architecture

I'm having some trouble to fit some concepts outlined in Uncle's Bob book into a NodeJs App. Could anybody help me?

About **Packaging by Component** and **Screaming Architecture**: how should I properly package a component in NodeJS?

[user's component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq0bg.png)

1 Should I have one package.json file per component?

2 How should I properly inject the UserRepository's implementation into the domain? Should the top class Users do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Clean Architecture the top level packages should reflect the core business purpose. So you should build your components according to your major business aspects and then create one or more packages per component. Multiple packages for a single component make sense if you want to separate business and technical aspects.

For a more detailed discussion on "building a screaming architecture" pls refer to my blog post: http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Scream/

Regarding your second question: in clean architecture the MAIN component is responsible for wiring up all other components and classes, so doing the dependency injection.